# Add json elements to a pandas data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas df which I have created. The structure of the df is as follows :-

```
  A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  NaN
2  x  y  z  NaN
.
.
```

Now also have a list **list1** which has json as elements like

```
[{a:1,b:2},{c:1,d:2},....]
```

I would like to add the elements in my list to the json pandas df so that my df looks like

```
  A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  {a:1,b:2}
2  x  y  z  {c:1,d:2}
.
.
```

when i did

```
df['D'].iloc[0] = list[0]
```

it gave me no index named error. What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions if `length` of `list1` is same as length of `DataFrame`:

You need create `Series` first with same index as `df` and then assign to new column:

```
print (pd.Series(list1, index=df.index))
0    {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2    {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
dtype: object

df['D'] = pd.Series(list1, index=df.index)
print (df)
  A  B  C                 D
0  a  b  c  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2  x  y  z  {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(D=pd.Series(list1, index=df.index))
print (df)
   A  B  C                 D
0  a  b  c  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2  x  y  z  {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Solution for comment, thank you [Nickil Maveli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760608/add-json-elements-to-a-pandas-data-frame/41760655?noredirect=1#comment70713011_41760655):

```
df.loc[:, 'D'] = list1
```

Or better:

```
df['D'] = list1

print (df)
   A  B  C                 D
0  a  b  c  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2  x  y  z  {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
```

If lenghts are different, it is a bit more complicated - need select by position by `length` of `df.index` and by `length` of `list1`:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C   D
0  a  b  c NaN
2  x  y  z NaN
5  y  e  t NaN

list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':2}]
df['D'] = pd.Series(list1[:len(df.index)], index=df.index[:len(list1)])
print (df)
   A  B  C                 D
0  a  b  c  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2  x  y  z  {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
5  y  e  t               NaN
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C   D
0  a  b  c NaN
2  x  y  z NaN
5  y  e  t NaN

list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':2}, {'a':1,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':2}]
df['D'] = pd.Series(list1[:len(df.index)], index=df.index[:len(list1)])
print (df)
   A  B  C                 D
0  a  b  c  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
2  x  y  z  {'d': 2, 'c': 1}
5  y  e  t  {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Won't a simple `loc` be sufficient here - `df.loc[:, 'D'] = L` ?